# How to automatically forward all sms from Windows 10 mobile to PC?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, lumia, sms, pc

Is there an app or settings to allow me to automatically forward all my SMS from my Windows 10 mobile (phone) to my windows 10 PC (email or an app like is available for iPhones and android phones)?
Thanks

Comment: I think that skype should do this synchronization.

Comment: Are you using the same user account on both the phone and Windows desktop? I see all SMS ok the desktop without any app.